# cant start the kafka server in my directory kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

i want to start my very first kafka, but when i tried to run this on my kafka_2.13-2.8.0 directory `bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .. \ .. \config\zookeeper.properties`

why it returns `\Kafka\kafka_2.13-2.8.0\bin\windows\../ ../config/log4j.properties was unexpected at this time`

idk i already followed this tip to install kafka https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYVyRh4C94E&t=303s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known error in the Kafka log4j settings, especially if the install path contains spaces or non alphanumeric characters

If you really want to run Kafka on Windows, you should [use WSL2 anyway](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/), or Docker. Otherwise, assuming you did get the bat file working, you'd eventually run into other errors that crash the broker